# How shall I Quickly compare two generic lists and it's contents for checking if they are identical?

Tags: c#, for-loop, foreach, generic-list

**//Here I have a List of Lists**

```
List<List<T>> SelectionList = new List<List<T>>();
```

**//My current code to compare lists**

```
    for(int i = 0; i < SelectionList.Count; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < SelectionList.Count; j++)
        {
            if (SelectionList[i].Equals(SelectionList[j]))
            {
                SelectionList.Remove(SelectionList[j]);
            }
        }
    }
```

//**Note:** The above code supposedly works, in cases where the contents of both the lists are ordered ie., they are in same index, but in my lists they might be same but list contents are shuffled. in this case it fails to identify.

//Basically I need to remove any repetitions of same list in my list of lists;

Comment: _"The above code supposedly works"_ - I do not believe so. This should remove all the lists, because it checks every list for equality to itself (case i == j). Also, this mutates the data structure it is iterating. That is a big "No No". _If_ you have lists left after this code has run, it is probably a sideeffect of the latter issue I mentioned. I am afraid this does not _help_ you very much. I just wanted to point you to issues with this code, that you are obviously not aware of.

Comment: sure, Thank you for denoting me the issues

Comment: To step towards a solution for you, we need to make some additional assumptions about `T`: it should be somwhow equatable. For example, if we could assume that two "identical" instances of T have the same HashCode, we could build a position-agnostic HashCode for the whole List, which would mean: same HashCode of the list => same Items regardless of their order. Then the whole problem would boil down to making those distinct. Which could be done in various ways. Thereof, I would probably implement some an Benchmark them to find the most appropriate.

Comment: Can the individual lists contain duplicate entries, e.g. could one of the lists be [1, 2, 2, 3, 4]?

Comment: No, it will not - my list has unique set of values like [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If (and only if) the following is true:

- Your individual lists do not contain any duplicates
- The type `T` of your list elements implements `IComparable` and `GetHashCode()` correctly

Then you can remove each list that matches an earlier list like so (note that you must traverse the list backwards when removing items from the end of it otherwise the loop indices could go out of range):

```
for (int i = lists.Count - 1; i > 0; i--)
{
    for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--)
    {
        if (!lists[i].Except(lists[j]).Any())
        {
            lists.RemoveAt(i);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The important line here is: `!lists[i].Except(lists[j]).Any()`.

Let's break it down:

`lists[i].Except(lists[j])`: - This produces a sequence of all the elements of `lists[i]` that are NOT in `lists[j]`, regardless of order.

Thus if all of the items in `lists[j]` are also in `lists[j]`, this will produce an empty sequence; otherwise, it will produce a non-empty sequence.

The `.Any()` will return `true` for a non-empty sequence, and `false` for an empty sequence.

So `lists[i].Except(lists[j]).Any()` will return `false` if the items are the same in each list and `true` if they differ.

This is the opposite of what we want for the `lists.RemoveAt()` so we just negate the result, giving the final code `!lists[i].Except(lists[j]).Any()`.

Compilable console app:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var lists = new List<List<int>>
        {
            new() {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, // [0]
            new() {2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, // [1]
            new() {3, 4, 5, 6, 7}, // [2]
            new() {5, 4, 3, 2, 1}, // [3] Dupe of [0]
            new() {4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, // [4]
            new() {6, 5, 4, 3, 2}, // [5] Dupe of [1]
            new() {5, 6, 7, 8, 9}, // [6] 
            new() {3, 4, 5, 2, 1}, // [7] Dupe of [0]
            new() {6, 7, 8, 9, 0}  // [8]
        };

        for (int i = lists.Count - 1; i > 0; i--)
        {
            for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--)
            {
                if (!lists[i].Except(lists[j]).Any())
                {
                    lists.RemoveAt(i);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < lists.Count; ++i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", lists[i]));
        }
    }
```

Try it on DotNetFiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/nWnOcP

Answer (score 0):

If, for each list, each possible value appears at most once in the list, you could use a `Dictionary<T,int>` to store how often an element appears. Then you perform the following steps:

1. Iterate over the lists, and, for each list, do the following: For each list element `k`, check if the dictionary contains it as a key. If it does not, then add key `k` with value `1` to your dictionary. If it does, then increment the value for key `k` by `1`.
2. Iterate over the dictionary's elements and check that all values are `2` (if you have two lists) or `n` (if you have `n` lists).

Answer (score 0):

Your way is not correct, as you said, try this:

you should iterate the following procedure over your list-Of-Lists;

```
private bool Compare(List<T> List1,List<T> List2)
{
   var infirstNotSecond = list1.Except(list2).ToList();
   var insecondNotFirst = list2.Except(list1).ToList();
   return !infirstNotSecond.Any() && !insecondNotFirst.Any();
}
```